# Why calling XMLParser(contentsOfURL: rssURL) is giving error: 'Argument passed to call that takes no arguments'?

Tags: ios, swift, xml-parsing

I've been working through this tutorial https://www.appcoda.com/building-rss-reader-using-uisplitviewcontroller-uipopoverviewcontroller/
part way through it talks about using NSXMLParser to parse an RSS feed:

Here is the original snippet method:

```
func startParsingWithContentsOfURL(rssURL: NSURL) {
        let parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: rssURL)
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
    }
```

However, I see that NSXMLParser is now XMLParser. I've been trying this:

```
 func startParsingWithContentsOfURL(rssURL: NSURL) {
        func startParsingWithContentsOfURL(rssURL: NSURL) {
            let parser = XMLParser(contentsOfURL: rssURL)
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
        }
    }
```

Which is a model that I've seen elsewhere but it's giving the error 'Argument passed to call that takes no arguments'. While I thought the error was self explanatory, I've seen such code elsewhere in a similar form which seems to (apparently) work for others.

The other thing I tried was:

```
let parser = XMLParser.init(contentsOf: rssURL)
```

However I get the same error - any idea what I've done wrong?

Comment: 1. Which line is causing the error? 2. Why is the `startParsingWithContentsOfURL` function inside another `startParsingWithContentsOfURL` function?

Comment: let parser = XMLParser(contentsOfURL: rssURL)
this one.

Comment: Again, why is one function inside another function of the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better find a modern article than watching some archeological remains of an ancient Swift.

As you see, `NSXMLParser` is renamed to `XMLParser`, and a new type `URL` is introduced.

```
func startParsingWithContentsOfURL(rssURL: URL) {
    guard let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: rssURL) else {
        //...
        return
    }
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
}
```

Please check [the latest documentations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/xmlparser).

---

**UPDATE**

Please try this:

```
func startParsingWithContentsOfURL(rssURL: URL) {
    guard let parser = Foundation.XMLParser(contentsOf: rssURL) else {
        //...
        return
    }
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
}
```

In the old, old tutorial, you define a class `XMLParser`. So, you may need to distinguish two `XMLParser`s, Apple's and your own.

I strongly, strongly and very strongly recommend you to find a modern tutorial or example written for modern Swift.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However the same error is returned.

Comment: @laurie, I cannot find _the same error_ with my code. Though, I may be mistaking what was wrong, as I cannot reproduce `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments`. You may be defining another `XMLParser` in your project.

Comment: Thankyou! The updated version doesn't throw the error. Believe me, if I could find an updated version I would use it! I'm looking to build a basic RSS reader and then build further functionality off that.

Comment: @laurie, I could have found many articles or example codes searching with "swift rss reader", and some of them are written in modern Swift (4 or 5). Better check it is written in these last two years or less. You should better visit two or three pages in the search result.